# TempData Like Object in WebForms - Session State for only 1 Additional Request

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, session, webforms

I would like to store some objects *only for one request* through the session state.  I can't seem to think of an easy way to accomplish this. This is *exactly* what ASP.NET MVC's TempData object does.  Could anyone provide me with a link or some examples of how to have an object in session state only survive one additional request?

I was thinking, this could be possibly accomplished by making a custom dictionary object, which stores an age (# of requests) on each item. By subscribing to the Application_BeginRequest and Application_EndRequest methods, you could perform the required cleanup of the objects.  This could even probably facilitate making an object that stored a piece of data for X requests, not just one.  Is this on the right track?

Comment: The approach you describe is exactly how I would've implemented it.

Comment: Okay one problem with my approach: the Session object is null in both of those methods.  Anyone have an idea where I can stick the cleanup code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I implemented something very similar to what you describe in the Application_AcquireRequestState method of Global.ascx.cs. All my session objects are wrapped in a class that keeps count of the number of reads.

```
// clear any session vars that haven't been read in x requests
List<string> keysToRemove = new List<string>();
for (int i = 0; HttpContext.Current.Session != null && i < HttpContext.Current.Session.Count; i++)
{
    var sessionObject = HttpContext.Current.Session[i] as SessionHelper.SessionObject2;
    string countKey = "ReadsFor_" + HttpContext.Current.Session.Keys[i];
    if (sessionObject != null/* && sessionObject.IsFlashSession*/)
    {
        if (HttpContext.Current.Session[countKey] != null)
        {
            if ((int)HttpContext.Current.Session[countKey] == sessionObject.Reads)
            {
                keysToRemove.Add(HttpContext.Current.Session.Keys[i]);
                continue;
            }
        }
        HttpContext.Current.Session[countKey] = sessionObject.Reads;
    }
    else if (HttpContext.Current.Session[countKey] != null)
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Session.Remove(countKey);
    }
}

foreach (var sessionKey in keysToRemove)
{
    string countKey = "ReadsFor_" + sessionKey;
    HttpContext.Current.Session.Remove(sessionKey);
    HttpContext.Current.Session.Remove(countKey);
}
```

Comment: What does `SessionHelper.SessionObject2` look like?

Answer (score -2):

You can find something very similar here : http://maff.ailoo.net/2009/06/build-a-flashmessenger-system-in-aspnet-mvc/