# Is it possible to put a variable only for the next request?

Tags: c#, .net, request

I'd like to do this :

1. Simple request to the server;
2. Put a variable that will be visible ONLY to the next request;
3. Make a redirect (Response.Redirect, without any querystring);
4. Well, the page that I'll see is called by the previous "request" : now I'll access to the variable stored at point (2). The variable now will be destroyed;
5. Any other request can't find that variable, until I call the same page of point (1);

is there any mechanism to doing that? without having a querystring system... I know there are many scope in .NET...

Comment: You could use the [`PreviousPage`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.previouspage.aspx) property.

Comment: @TimSchmelter don't think that works with `Response.Redirect` though.

Comment: @Magnus: No, only with `Server.Transfer`, but is this set in stone?

Comment: @TimSchmelter If not, yours is the best answer so far.

Comment: Keep in mind that the concept of "the next request" is somewhat arbitrary in a web application, where the user could refresh the page or could be browsing your site with multiple browser tabs/windows open, or your pages could have JavaScript that makes Ajax calls back to your web server, which also count as requests. Most likely what you want to do is store your data in Session until you access it later, at which point you want to remove it from Session. If you're using the ASP.NET MVC framework, it has a TempData collection that provides this behavior for you.

Comment: If it were me, I would consider whether I really want to remove the data from Session. If the user refreshes the page after you've redirected, then the value will be gone, and I'm guessing that you won't refresh properly. That's probably not a big deal, but if you wanted to handle that scenario, then one thought is to use a unique, randomly generated key to store the data in Session, and then pass that random key in the query string for your redirect.  That way, you can refresh the page (with the key in the query string), and it won't conflict with other requests (because it is random/unique)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it can be done.

1. Create the page (or controller action if using MVC) to receive the data. If you are using an HTTP GET request, the key-value pair will be on the query string. If you are using an HTTP POST, the key-value pair will be part of the post data (Forms).
2. Once you receive the key-value pair, store the data in some persistent location, such as the session or a database.
3. Redirect to a new page.
4. In the new page, retrieve the data from the persistent store and process it.

Comment: well, but it is on session. It will be placed until the session will destroy...and it is not what I'm looking for...

Comment: @markzzz you can always remove it from session when your done with it yourself.

Comment: If that's bad, then store it in a database?

Comment: this does have race conditions with opening up the page several times in different tabs/windows.

Comment: That is true of most session-based activity. If you are going to perform the same task in the same session under multiple threads, you have to code for that.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using ASP.NET MVC3 there is a special collection for exactly this, called `TempData`. Anything you put in there is available to the next request, but no longer.

For web forms there is a duplicate question here on SO: [TempData Like Object in WebForms - Session State for only 1 Additional Request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1350019/tempdata-like-object-in-webforms-session-state-for-only-1-additional-request)

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, TempData has changed in the more recent versions (MVC 2+ I think) so that the values persist until they are accessed, at which point they are automatically removed from session (which is the underlying container for TempData).

Answer (score 0):

If `Response.Redirect` is not set in stone, you could use `Server.Transfer` instead and [`Page.PreviousPage`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.previouspage%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) to access the first page directly.

> When you use the Transfer method or use cross-page posting to transfer
>   processing from one ASP.NET page to another, the originating page
>   contains request information that might be required for the
>   destination page. You can use the PreviousPage property to access that
>   information.
>
> If the current page is being rendered as a result of a direct request
>   (not a transfer or cross-post from another page), the PreviousPage
>   property contains null.

So for example in the first page(*RedirectForm.aspx*):

```
public String Value { get; set; }

protected void BtnTransfer_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Value = "Foo";
    Server.Transfer("Transfer.aspx");
}
```

and in `Transfer.aspx`:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Page.PreviousPage != null)
    {
        RedirectForm prev = (RedirectForm)Page.PreviousPage;
        String prevValue = prev.Value;  // "Foo"
    }
}
```

Comment: If using `Server.Transfer`, then one could also store values in the `HttpContext.Current.Items` collection, which retains data for only the current request.